# SSAS: Move tempdb database

Tags: ssas

For SQL server 2008 R2 Analysis services, how can I move tempdb database files from one drive to another? At the time of installation, I didn't have a separate drive for tempdb. Now that I do have one, I need to move to the new drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to alter the location using ALTER DATABASE tempdb MODIFY FILE location and restart SQL Server. SQL Server will automatically create the tempdb in the new location but you may have to go to the old location to delete the (old) files.

See Moving the tempdb database in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345408.aspx

Comment: I want to move analysis services tempdb database not SQL server database engine.

Comment: Manjot, I don't work with Analysis services but I don't think Analysis services doesn't have a separate tempdb IIRC.

Answer (score 4):

Connect to your Analysis Services server in SQL Management Studio.  Right-click the server, then click Properties in the menu.  In the Properties dialog, check the "Show Advanced (All) Properties" check box at the bottom of the list.  Then, in the grid above that check box, set the location you want for SSAS TempDB in the "TempDir" setting.

You will have to restart SQL Server Analysis Services for the change to take effect.